# Ansible Playbook to push hostname to ip addresses

Tags: ansible

I have a CSV file that has the host name with corresponding IP address in it. I am trying to write an ansible playbook using the lineinfile = command with a variable that will read the CSV file and place the hostname of the corresponding ipaddress on the host with the ipaddress. I don't know if this is the way to go.  I want to run it with the playbook addressed to all host.

Comment: Please add csv file samples: what do you have and what do you want to achieve after processing.

Comment: My CSV file looks like this: ip address, hostname

Answer (score 0):

If you need to connect to all hosts in your csv file and set hostname to corresponding name value from that file, this will do:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - add_host: name="{{ item.split(',')[1] | trim }}" ansible_host="{{ item.split(',')[0] }}" group=csv
      with_lines: cat host-ip.csv

- hosts: csv
  tasks:
    - hostname: name="{{ inventory_hostname }}"
```